# Nifi not accessible via Web UI when started using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I am running nifi via docker-compose using the below command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-nifi.yaml up
```

Also, a subnet was created before running docker-compose command.

```
docker network create nifi-docker_default --subnet=192.168.200.0/24
```

As per the docker logs, I can see it is up and running.

```
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,911 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarAutoLoader Starting NAR Auto-Loader for directory ./extensions ...
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,911 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarAutoLoader NAR Auto-Loader started
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,912 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,912 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://192.168.200.4:8099/nifi
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,919 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
ESC[33mnifi_1       |ESC[0m 2021-05-07 05:53:09,919 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 41045176649 nanoseconds (41 seconds).
```

However, I am not able to access it via Web UI by running either http://192.168.200.4:8099/nifi OR http://localhost:8099/nifi OR http://127.0.0.1:8099/nifi.

I checked for Firewall as well and it is not blocked.

```
[root@pdkjoshi orchestration]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Below is the output of `docker ps` command.

```
[root@pdkjoshi ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                               NAMES
f3b8ef4da5d0   nginx                "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8099->8099/tcp, :::8099->8099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8999->8999/tcp, :::8999->8999/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp, :::9090->9090/tcp                                                                             orchestration_nginx_1
7efe77c16e7c   apache/nifi:1.12.1   "../scripts/start.sh"    About an hour ago   Up About an hour   8080/tcp, 8443/tcp, 10000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49160->8000/tcp, :::49160->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49159->8082/tcp, :::49159->8082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49158->8099/tcp, :::49158->8099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49157->9443/tcp, :::49157->9443/tcp   orchestration_nifi_1
6019f0144e62   redis                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   6379/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                            orchestration_redis_1
7d8a141a47b4   bitnami/zookeeper    "/opt/bitnami/script…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 3888/tcp                                                                                                            orchestration_zookeeper_1
```

Below is my web properties section of *nifi.properties*

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=192.168.200.4
nifi.web.http.port=8099
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
```

Below is docker-compose-nifi.yaml file.

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    environment:
        NIFI_NETWORK_NAME: ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
        NIFI_MOUNT_PATH: ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-~/.aws}
        NIFI_AWS_PATH: ${NIFI_AWS_PATH-.}
    ports:
      # - "9443:9443" # DIRECT UI
      - "8099:8099" # NIFI DEV PROXY
      - "9090:9090" # NIFI PROD PROXY
      - "8999:8999" #
    networks:
      - ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
    depends_on:
      - nifi
    volumes:
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nginx/nifi-cert.pem:/etc/nginx/nifi-cert.pem
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nginx/CN=nifi.key:/etc/nginx/nifi.key
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nginx/CN=nifi.pem:/etc/nginx/nifi.pem

  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.12.1
    environment:
      NIFI_JVM_DEBUGGER: DEBUG
      AWS_PROFILE: ${AWS_PROFILE-aws-validata}
      AWS_REGION: ${AWS_REGION-us-east-1}
      NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT: 1 min
      NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT: 8082
      NIFI_CLUSTER_MODE: ${NIFI_CLUSTER_MODE-true}
      ATHENA_JDBC: ${ATHENA_JDBC-validata}
      NIFI_JVM_HEAP_MAX: 5G
      NIFI_NETWORK_NAME: ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
      NIFI_MOUNT_PATH: ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-~/.aws}
      NIFI_AWS_PATH: ${NIFI_AWS_PATH-.}
    networks:
      - ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
    ports:
      - 8099
      - 8082
      - 9443
      - 8000
    volumes:
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/scripts/modeln.sh:/opt/nifi/scripts/modeln.sh
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/scripts/start.sh:/opt/nifi/scripts/start.sh
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/users.xml:/opt/nifi/modeln/users.xml
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/flow.xml:/opt/nifi/modeln/flow.xml
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/nifi.properties:/opt/nifi/modeln/nifi.properties
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/nifi_http.properties:/opt/nifi/modeln/nifi_http.properties
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/authorizations.xml:/opt/nifi/modeln/authorizations.xml
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/authorizers.xml:/opt/nifi/modeln/authorizers.xml
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/truststore.jks:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/truststore.jks
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/conf/keystore.jks:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/keystore.jks
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/nifi/data:/opt/nifi/data
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/../lib/aws-assume-role-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/bootstrap/aws-assume-role-plugin.jar
      - ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-.}/../lib/modeln-ncpdp-nar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/modeln-ncpdp.nar
      - ${NIFI_AWS_PATH-~/.aws}:/home/nifi/.aws
    links:
      - "zookeeper:zookeeper"
      - "redis:redis"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181" #
      - "8080:8080" #
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "true"
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888
      NIFI_NETWORK_NAME: ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
      NIFI_MOUNT_PATH: ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-~/.aws}
      NIFI_AWS_PATH: ${NIFI_AWS_PATH-.}
    networks:
      - ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
  redis:
    image: 'redis'
    environment:
      NIFI_NETWORK_NAME: ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
      NIFI_MOUNT_PATH: ${NIFI_MOUNT_PATH-~/.aws}
      NIFI_AWS_PATH: ${NIFI_AWS_PATH-.}
    networks:
      - ${NIFI_NETWORK_NAME-nifi-docker_default}
networks:
  nifi-docker_default:
    external: true
```

Please let me know how if I am missing something to access it via webUI.

Comment: You need to show us the relevant bits of `docker-compose-nifi.yaml`

Comment: Provided  docker-compose-nifi.yaml file.

Comment: Ok, this should work on http://localhost:8099 (or maybe https). Can you show us some of the logs pls?

Comment: Accessing localhost:8099 (or maybe https did not work. PFA log - https://www.dropbox.com/s/do6ag5str0kcezk/log_nifi_start.log?dl=0